C++ Not being in input twice
enter code hereI am making a calculator that works with imaginary numbers. When I run it in the terminal I am able to put the first two inputs however the second one glitches out.(Look at screenshot for reference) Here is my Handler with get_complex_input() that runs at this part and Complex file.
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#pragma once

class Complex {
private:
    float real;
    float imaginary;

public:
    Complex() : real(0), imaginary(0) {}

    Complex(float r, float i) : real(r), imaginary(i) {}

    Complex operator+(Complex rhs) {
        return Complex(this->real + rhs.real, this->imaginary + rhs.imaginary);
    }
    Complex operator-(Complex rhs) {
        return Complex(this->real - rhs.real, this->imaginary - rhs.imaginary);
    }
    Complex operator*(const Complex& other) const {
        float new_real = (this->real * other.real) - (this->imaginary * other.imaginary);
        float new_imaginary = (this->real * other.imaginary) + (this->imaginary * other.real);
        return Complex(new_real, new_imaginary);
    }

    Complex operator/(const Complex& other) const {
        float denominator = (other.real * other.real) + (other.imaginary * other.imaginary);
        float new_real = ((this->real * other.real) + (this->imaginary * other.imaginary)) / denominator;
        float new_imaginary = ((this->imaginary * other.real) - (this->real * other.imaginary)) / denominator;
        return Complex(new_real, new_imaginary);
    }

    // Function to find the conjugate of a complex number
    Complex conjugate() {
        return Complex(this->real, -(this->imaginary));
    }

    // A helper function to print the complex number
    void print() const {
        if (imaginary >= 0)
            cout << real << " + " << imaginary << "i" << endl;
        else
            cout << real << " - " << -imaginary << "i" << endl;
    }
};

#include <iostream>
#include "Complex.h"
#pragma once
using namespace std;

class Handler {
public:
    // Function to display the menu and get the user's choice
    static int print_and_get_choices() {
        int choice;
        cout << "Complex Numbers Calculator" << endl;
        cout << "1. Add two complex numbers" << endl;
        cout << "2. Subtract two complex numbers" << endl;
        cout << "3. Multiply two complex numbers" << endl;
        cout << "4. Divide two complex numbers" << endl;
        cout << "5. Find the conjugate of a complex number" << endl;
        cout << "6. Exit" << endl;
        cout << "Enter your choice: ";
        cin >> choice;
        return choice;
    }

    // Function to add two complex numbers
    static void add_two_complex_numbers() {
        Complex num1 = get_complex_input();
        Complex num2 = get_complex_input();
        Complex result = num1 + num2;
        cout << "Result of addition: ";
        result.print();
    }

    // Function to subtract two complex numbers
    static void subtract_two_complex_numbers() {
        Complex num1 = get_complex_input();
        Complex num2 = get_complex_input();
        Complex result = num1 - num2;
        cout << "Result of subtraction: ";
        result.print();
    }

    // Function to multiply two complex numbers
    static void multiply_two_complex_numbers() {
        Complex num1 = get_complex_input();
        Complex num2 = get_complex_input();
        Complex result = num1 * num2;
        cout << "Result of multiplication: ";
        result.print();
    }

    // Function to divide two complex numbers
    static void divide_two_complex_numbers() {
        Complex num1 = get_complex_input();
        Complex num2 = get_complex_input();
        Complex result = num1 / num2;
        cout << "Result of division: ";
        result.print();
    }

    // Function to find the conjugate of a complex number
    static void find_conjugate_of_a_complex_number() {
        Complex num = get_complex_input();
        Complex result = num.conjugate();
        cout << "Conjugate: ";
        result.print();
    }

private:
    // Helper function to get user input for a complex number
    static Complex get_complex_input() {
        float real, imaginary;
        cout << "Enter the real part: ";
        cin >> real;
        cout << "Enter the imaginary part: ";
        cin >> imaginary;
        return Complex(real, imaginary);
    }
};

I just want to make the inputs work to check my functions. Also, using ./a.out on the folder terminal if that means anything

Don't quote the code, select the code and apply a code block { }  in the SO editor.

Problem with input? Then you don't need all the math stuff in your [mre]. Leave just enough code in there to show your problem in action.

There is no screenshot, can't see what the problem is.

I don't see a screenshot so I can't see how it glitches out - can you please upload the screenshot?  By the way, you do know there is a std::complex?

Did you perhaps enter a letter when your code expects float? E.g., for Enter the real part: you enter 13 and for Enter the imaginary part: you enter 1i?

You are not checking the error state of cin after reading a value to make sure the input didn't fail.

All those this->s and (redundant parentheses) gave me a headache. float new_real = (this->real * other.real) - (this->imaginary * other.imaginary) can (and should) be written float new_real = real * other.real - imaginary * other.imaginary.

The screen shot showing your trial run was missing. It is likely, however, that you are entering i after the imaginary part of a complex number.
Suppose, for example, you are adding 1+2.5i and 2-5i.
The first complex number will be input correctly, but when your program tries to input the real part of second, it will fail. That happens because the character i remains in the input stream from the first complex number.
Here is what happened when I tried your program on my system:
Enter the real part: 1
Enter the imaginary part: 2.5i     <-------- 2.5 inputs okay, but `i` remains unread
Enter the real part: Enter the imaginary part: Result of addition: 1 - 1.07374e+08i

When cin >> real sees the character i, it fails, and places std::cin into a failed state. After that, all subsequent operations with std::cin will fail. You can see that in the example above, where the attempt to input the imaginary part of the second number failed.
A simple workaround/fix is to input numbers only. Do not enter i after the imaginary part. Otherwise, you can require the user to enter the i, but if you do, you will need to input i into a variable of type char.
char ch{};
float real, imaginary;
std::cout << "Enter the real part: ";
std::cin >> real;
std::cout << "Enter the imaginary part: ";
std::cin >> imaginary;
std::cin.get(ch);  // No whitespace is allowed before the character `i`.
if (ch != 'i') { /* error */ }

Whether or not you allow the user to enter i, you may want to use dedicated functions for console input.
Robust input routines
I generally call a function whenever I want the user to enter a number. That way, I can trap invalid entries, and have the user try again.
Function get_float (below) is an example. I added it to your Handler class.
class Handler {
    // ...
private:
    // Dedicated function to input a `float`.
    static float get_float(std::string const& prompt) {
        for (;;) {
            std::cout << prompt;
            if (float n{}; !(std::cin >> n)) {
                std::cout << "Invalid entry. Please reenter.\n\n";
                std::cin.clear();
                std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            }
            else {
                return n;
            }
        }
    }

    // Helper function to get user input for a complex number
    static Complex get_complex_input() {
        float real{ get_float("Enter the real part: ") };
        float imaginary{ get_float("Enter the imaginary part: ") };
        return Complex(real, imaginary);
    }
};

When get_float detects a failure, it puts std::cin back into a "good" state, by calling std::cin.clear(). Afterwards, it discards the characters still in the stream, by calling std::cin.ignore.
Here is what happened when I added get_floatto the program in the OP:
Enter the real part: 1
Enter the imaginary part: 2.5i      <----- Whoops. I entered `i`.
Enter the real part: Invalid entry. Please reenter.

Enter the real part: 2
Enter the imaginary part: -5        <----- No `i` this time.
Result of addition: 3 - 2.5i

A dedicated function for integer input
Function get_int (below) is similar to get_float, except it adds a feature that allows you to specify the range of values that are acceptable.
get_int can be used to tighten up your menu system.
class Handler {
    static int print_and_get_choices() {
        std::cout << 
            "Complex Numbers Calculator" 
            "\n"
            "\n 1. Add two complex numbers"
            "\n 2. Subtract two complex numbers"
            "\n 3. Multiply two complex numbers"
            "\n 4. Divide two complex numbers"
            "\n 5. Find the conjugate of a complex number"
            "\n 6. Exit"
            "\n\n";
        int const choice{ get_int("Enter your choice: ", 1, 6) };
        std::cout << '\n';
        return choice;
    }
    // ...
private:
    // Dedicated function to input an `int`.
    static int get_int(
        std::string const& prompt,
        int const min,
        int const max)
    {
        for (;;) {
            std::cout << prompt;
            if (int n{}; !(std::cin >> n)) {
                std::cout << "Invalid entry. Please reenter.\n\n";
                std::cin.clear();
                std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            }
            else if (n < min || n > max) {
                std::cout << "Invalid entry. Please reenter.\n"
                    << "Entries must be between " << min << " and " << max << ".\n\n";
            }
            else {
                return n;
            }
        }
    }
};

